# Bundle ID on Itunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am having a problem here in itunes connect. My bundle ID is "myapp" on itunesconnect, please note this is an app that i have already submitted. Now i am trying to implement push notification.

So i created a new app ID com.domain.app. But as usual it wont accept the app while uploading saying the Bundle Id is different as usual. So if i rename the application and upload a new application, will i be able to set the version as 1.x or should i set it to 1.0?

Many thanks :)

Comment: Are you trying to send this out as an update or an entirely new application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upload the newly named application with a new bundle ID, then yes, you may start the version out at 1.0 all over again, or whatever version number you desire for that matter. As far as iTunes Connect is concerned, it is a new application, and not actually an update of the product. Of course, in doing so, you will also need to have created a new distribution provisioning profile as well.

If you are adding features to an existing product, why a change of name and/or bundle ID?

Comment: hello thanks for the reply :) in fact i am trying to implement push notifications, so cannot create a provisioning with same bundle id

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to submit new app to implement push notification. You can add version implementing  this feature. You need to make an explicit app ID [if your previous App id is wild card type] same as your bundle id of current project with push notification enabled. Then make a distribution provisioning certificate using it. Then sign, validate and submit to app store.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to retain this as an update, you will need to retain the same bundle ID when submitting. The Application Loader will check all that and block you from submitting. Your application info must match what you have in iTunesConnect. Any differences will kick you out. You also can't go backwards in version numbers for updates. New applications are of course fine.